# TIME_LIMIT_EXCEEDED: Codeforces 686D

Tags: c++, performance

i was trying to solve this problem on codeforces http://codeforces.com/contest/686/problem/D, but i got TLE. could you tell me what takes so much time in my solution? is it data structures that i use or is the algorithm inefficient? how can i improve it?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int assignweights(int index, int weights[], vector<vector<int> > &v){
    if(v[index].size()==0){
        return 0;
    }else{
        vector<int> children=v[index];
        int result=0;
        result+=children.size();
        for(int i=0; i<children.size(); ++i){
            result+=assignweights(children[i], weights, v);
        }
        weights[index]=result;
    }
    return weights[index];
}


void getcentroid(int index, vector<vector<int> > &v, int weights[], int & result, int n){
        vector<int> children=v[index];
        bool b=false;
        for(int i=0; i<children.size(); ++i){
            if(weights[children[i]]+1>n/2){
                if(!result)getcentroid(children[i], v, weights, result, n);
                else break;
                b=true;
            }
        }
    if(!b){
        result=index+1;
    }
}


int main(){
    int n, q;
    cin>>n>>q;
    vector<vector<int> > v;
    for(int i=0; i<n; ++i){
        vector<int> vv;
        v.push_back(vv);
    }
    for(int i=1; i<=n-1; ++i){
        int a;
        cin>>a;
        v[a-1].push_back(i);
    }
    int weights[n];
    for(int i=0; i<n; ++i){
        weights[i]=0;
    }
    assignweights(0, weights, v);
    for(int i=0; i<q; ++i){
        int index;
        cin>>index;
        index--;
        int result=0;
        getcentroid(index, v, weights, result, weights[index]);
        cout<<result<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The first loop in the `main` function can be avoided. The second loop can be a single call to `std::copy` (though a loop might be good to reserve memory for the vectors). In the `assignweights` and `getcentroid` functions you copy a vector, instead of having a reference. There are probably other small things that can be optimized or improved.

Comment: Oh, and C++ doesn't have [variable-length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) so your definition of `weights` in the `main` function is really not valid. Use `std::vector` here too.

Comment: `vector<int> children` --> `const vector<int>& children`.

Comment: but i have reference sign "&" for vectors in function parameters

Comment: @shotakobaxidze In the function *arguments* yes, but what about the local variables `children`?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg thanks, but sadly it didn't work, tle again :(

Answer (score 2):

In the worse test case, your solution my have complexity of O(n*q).
I think the best solution for this problem is for each node of the tree, you create a vector of its descendants at index 1,2,4,...2^x upon it.
With that vector, for each query, it takes O(log(n)) to find the answer.